# Difference between "face of" and "faces of" in Hebrew

Tags: grammar-dikduk

If you want to say "face of gold" (sing.) in Hebrew, you say פני זהב.

If you want to say "faces of gold" (plural) in Hebrew, you say _______.

Part of the difficulty is that the Hebrew word for "face", פנים, is one of those [unique nouns](https://www.hebrewpod101.com/lesson/absolute-beginner-questions-answered-by-your-hebrew-teacher-16-why-is-the-word-%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-panim-meaning-face-plural/) which are plural in their grammatical form, but singular conceptually. That being the case, is there any way to identify between whether a verse means "face of" or "faces of", assuming there weren't other telling signs in the verse?

A few examples:

- In [Bamidbar 20:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.20.10?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&aliyot=0), when it speaks of **פני** הסלע, is there any way to know whether it means "face of" or "faces of" the rock?
- In the words ([from the Ramban](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Deuteronomy.31.17.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=he)) of הסתר **פני** הגאולה, is there any way to know whether he means "face" or "faces" of redemption?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say "faces of gold" (plural) in Hebrew, you *also* say פני זהב

...or, if you want to refer to particular gold faces made by Betzalel, you could say [פני הכרבים](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.25.20).

It seems that there's no difference in the word used in either case.

Comment: Is there any way to identify between whether a verse means "face of" or "faces of", assuming there weren't other telling signs in the verse?

Comment: I don't think so.  It's the same word.

Comment: @Chaim "John gave Jim the pants"

Comment: @doubleaa Your analogy can be clarified by saying, "John gave Jim the pairs of pants."  Is there any way to clarify the Hebrew ambiguity in OP question?

Comment: @DanF "Popeye gave me the fish"